# Intertitial ad finished load but not showing?

Tags: android, admob

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    StartAppSDK.init(this, "200155885", true);

    MobileAds.initialize(this,

            "ca-app-pub-6093358640755241~9410174132");

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6093358640755241/8773192961");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("22E1DBBDDEBAD8E53600D097657EFF08").build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("22E1DBBDDEBAD8E53600D097657EFF08").build());
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }

    });
```

Ad load finished but not showing the ad i also aded test device.

Comment: Is there any log ? Have you tried with google ad id?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `mInterstitialAd.show()` from a natural break point in your app.

Don't call it from `onAdClosed()`, this event occurs when the user closes the ad.

Don't call it from `onAdLoaded()` as this event occurs when an ad has been downloaded to your app, so happens at unpredictable times. Using this event to show the ad will get your account banned.

Answer (score 0):

hey try this may be help you to show ad

```
 mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("22E1DBBDDEBAD8E53600D097657EFF08").build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {

                Log.d("AD IN CONSTANT:", "AD CLOSED");



            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                mInterstitialAd.show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int in) {

                Log.d("AD IN CONSTANT:", "AD FAILED TO LOAD");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to show the ad on the "onAdClosed" closed event that is when the user dismiss the ad.

That doesn't make much sense, maybe you meant to show the ad on the adLoaded event:

```
@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    super.onAdLoaded();
    mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```